# Adding a class to the body of an inactive site using multisite

Tags: functions, multisite, css

I am using multisite and have made inactive one of the sites. I would like a way to add a class to the body tag of inactive sites so that I can in turn, use that class to add a note for admin to see from the front-end that the site is indeed inactive. Can the functions file be used to do this perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use the `body_class` filter. If all the sites use the same theme, you can get away with putting this in `functions.php` (in a child theme so your code doesn't get overwritten when the theme is updated), but if any sites have a different theme, you'll need to put it into a custom plugin (perhaps a MU plugin).

```
<?php
add_filter('body_class', 'wpse_299000_body_class');
function wpse_299000_body_class() {
    // check if current subsite is inactive, deleted, archived, or spammed
    $is_inactive = ms_site_check();
    // value will come back either true or false
    if($is_inactive == true) {
        // add your desired class to <body> - this example adds .inactive
        $classes[] = 'inactive';
    }
    // always return classes so none are taken away
    return $classes;
}
?>
```

You can also remove classes if needed.

Comment: Excellent. I am using the same theme for all sites so this will be great. I’m actually very surprised there was no answer anywhere else for this; seems it would be pretty handy for others. Thank you.